# Browser-prefixed CSS properties in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to add `box-flex` to a `<p>` using jQuery. For now, `box-flex` is browser-prefixed. For Chrome/Safari you can then do `-webkit-box-flex: 1` to set it. However, setting this property using jQuery does not work.

[JSBin that demonstrates the problem](http://jsbin.com/ekobuw)

```
// this does not work
element.css('-webkit-box-flex', 1);
```

I've tried setting `-webkit-box-flex`, `box-flex`, `WebkitBoxFlex`, `webkitBoxFlex` and probably a few more combinations I can't remember.

I need runtime-defined `box-flex` values for each box, so the code above is very simplified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try

```
element.css('-webkit-box-flex', '1');
```

(Note the extra quotes after the comma)

Comment: Yes, this works beautifully. I had to wait before SO would allow me to approve it... :)